# Select * from dropdown selection c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I have a dropdown menu and a gridview. The dropdown is linked with mysql database and displays  values (categories) from my database.

My question is, is there a way that I can write query which will display all the information from that selected value (category) in the gridview?

Code for dropdown (this runs at page load):

```
public void ddl_Cat()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            MySqlCommand sql_Category = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT(Category) FROM DVD", cs);
            cs.Open();

            MySqlDataReader ddlgetcat;
            ddlgetcat = sql_Category.ExecuteReader();
        }
    }
```

So far I do not have any code for the gridview

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you may want to prevent MySql injections with perimeters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this..

```
protected void ddlgetcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string category = ddlgetcat.SelectedValue.Text;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM DVD WHERE Category = '" + category +"';", cs);
    da.Fill(dt);
    gvGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    gvGridView1.DataBind();
}
```

This isn't tested but it will give you the general idea of how to do it. I also don't use MySql so you might have to change it around to make it work properly. Then in your gridview, I'd suggest using TemplateFields. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, this has given me a general idea and I've fiddled with it but no luck as I'm quite new to C#, will keep trying though.

Comment: what issue are you having? Any error messages or anything of that sort?

Comment: No error messages appear, it just doesn't enter data into the gridview

Comment: I made a silly error and this code works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean all the information inside table category? like name, desc ...etc?
in this case I think you should use your dropdown menu selected value as parameter in a query to populate the gridview in selectIndexChange for the dropdown menu.